# Spring MVC - Can't Login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have been working on this login page for a while now, trying to get it to work, but I don't know how to fix this last error.

I have a bCrypt encoding algorithm for my DB connected with JDBC and even when I enter the correct password, I keep getting redirected to the /login?error path.

JSP Page:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="user"
                action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/processLogin">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <label for="inputUser">Username: </label> <input name="username"
                            type="text" path="username" id="inputUser" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword">Password: </label> 
                        <input name="username" type="password" path="password"
                            id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                            required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label> <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                            Remember Password
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>

            </form:form>
```

Login Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String showLoginForm(Model model) {

    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "login";
}

@PostMapping("/processLogin")
public String processLogin(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {

    if (userService.findUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()) != null) {
        return "/management/dashboard";
    } else {
        return "/access-denied";
    }
}
```

User DAO:

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Override
@Transactional
public User findUser(String username, String password) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    password = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password);

    Query<User> theQuery = session.createQuery("from users where username=:username and password=:password",
            User.class);

    if (theQuery.getSingleResult() != null) {
        User user = theQuery.getSingleResult();
        session.close();
        return user;
    } else {
        session.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource securityDataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/management/**").authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/processLogin").defaultSuccessUrl("/management/dashboard").permitAll();

    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

}

@Bean
@Autowired
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Why this contraption. You are bypassing Spring Security with your login. You are also wiring a datasource, but if you have a different st ructure in your DB then spring expects it won't work. Also make sure you are actually using BCrypt in  your database. Also your query won't work (if that is even called) as the hash for the password changes each time.

Comment: I was thinking the same about the bCrypt query as it changes each time. How would I go about making the code congruent with Spring Security? I thought each time you would need to query the database and match it against the record?

Comment: You do a query for the user. Obtain the password and call the `matches` method on the password encoder. BUt as stated why are you doing all this? You can achieve the same in a much easier way.

Comment: I see, okay. What is the more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Just let your dao implement `UserDetailsService` and wire it into the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. Actually your current configuration doesn't make sense, you are configuring a jdbc instance of an `AuthenticationProvider` but implement login yourself. So either you are totally bypassing Spring Security, or you are just luckily that it kind of/ sort of works.

Comment: So the UserDetailsService actually handles the authentication of the user with the database?

Comment: No. It only retrieves the user, the default `AuthenticationProvider` handles the authentication.